# Django + uwsgi + nginx redirect to default page "Welcome to NGINX"

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm a very beginner in python and django. However I'm trying to create a server to deploy my application. But when I want to access my app, I always get the default nginx page "Welcome to nginx".

This server is on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)
I've installed nginx, python, django and uwsgi packages with apt.
Next I've created a django project to /var/www/djangoApps and a django app to /var/www/djangoApps/testApp

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/djangoApps :

```
server {
    listen 80
    server_name django.pommesky.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.django.pommesky.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.django.pommesky.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/djangoApps_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/djangoApps_error.log;

    location /media {
        alias /var/www/djangoApps/media/;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/djangoApps/static/;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/app/djangoApps/socket;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

And this is my /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/djangoApps.ini :

```
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoApps.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
chdir = /var/www/djangoApps
socket = /run/uwsgi/djangoApps/socket
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/djangoApps.log
```

The uwsgi log doesn't show anything, everything seems to run well, it finishes by spawned uWSGI worker ...
But /var/log/nginx/djangoApps_access.log; and /var/log/nginx/djangoApps_error.log; don't exist, which is very strange.
I can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration.
Please help me ...

Comment: Also: `nginx -V` with `--prefix=/usr/share/nginx` will always default to showing this root (unless there are other server blocks defined) (usually default "welcome to nginx") regardless whether you have it enabled or not in sites-enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The domain `django.pommesky.com` doesn't look like it's alive, so it's possible that Nginx is receiving requests with wrong `Host:` field in the [HTTP request header.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (sect. 14.23) So Nginx serves a `default` catch-all page.

You can disable the `default` Nginx site by removing the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` link, and then restarting the daemon.

```
sudo rm -v /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

You can reenable by recreating the link:

```
sudo ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

The other thing you can try is to setup Bind or another DNS daemon to serve a *fake* `pommesky.com` zone with all the subdomains you want and use that DNS while you're developing your site.

Of course you can also register that domain with a hosting provider, and then use the DNS zone editor in its control panel to setup your subdomains and all the [PTRs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-12) you want to whatever public IP addresses you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your answer get me on the right way, it was a problem in my symlink to my site. I dont't know why but i was broken. Now it's repair but i still have an error : "unavailable modifier requested: 0" in the uwsgi log. It seems to come from the link between uwsgi and python. Thanks again !