# Django + uWSGI + nginx 502 Internal Error (Permission Denied)

Tags: django, nginx

I've set up my site based on the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

However, when I go to the URL specified in my nginx sites-available settings, I just get the default nginx page ("welcome to nginx!"). I've tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809774/django-uwsgi-nginx-redirect-to-default-page-welcome-to-nginx), but even deleting /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default doesn't seem to do anything.

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/eng_blog file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name eng.camdar.io;

  location = /favicon.io {access_log off; log_not_found off;}
  location /static/ {
      root /root/eng_blog;
  }

  location / {
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/root/eng_blog/eng_blog.sock
  }
}
```

My /etc/uwsgi/sites/eng_blog.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = eng_blog
base = /root

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
wsgi-file = eng_blog/wsgi.py

master = True
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
vacuum = true
```

/etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid root
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

The tutorial claims that, after symlinking /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/eng_blog to /etc/nginx/sites-available/eng_blog, things should just "work", but I'm still seeing the default Nginx screen. Help?

EDIT:

I fixed the above issue by including sites-enabled in nginx.conf. However, now uwsgi seems to get permission denied errors, which is strange because I'm pretty sure I set all of the permissions right.

Comment: what are the user:group and permissions of eng_blog and eng_blog/wsgi.py?

Comment: root:www-data for and 664 for both

Comment: should be fine.. I don't know what's wrong. Maybe this can help you? http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html